# Use Enum for filtering in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, filter, enums

> How to use an `Enum` to filter in `p:dataTable`?

My approach looks like this:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{item.EMyEnum}" filterMatchMode="in"  >
    <f:facet name="filter">
        <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Select" onchange="PF('datatable').filter()">
            <f:selectItems value="#{MyEnum.values()}" />
            <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" onsuccess="PF('datatable').filter()"/>
        </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.EMyEnum}"/>
</p:column>
```

Everything looks fine, but when I select one item from the drop down, the whole content is filtered. When I deselect everything in the drop down, then the content comes up again, so basically the filter seems to work, but every comparison is evaluated to false. I do not understand why, as JSF has build in Enum-converters hasn't it? But what am I missing or doing wrong here?

I am working with PF 5.1 on Mojarra 2.1.29

---

I solved my problem with usage of a `List` of my `Enum` types in combination with the OmniFaces `GenericEnumConverter`. This works like charm, but I'd still like to know what exactly the problem with the previous solution is and how it could be fixed.

Comment: This is usually an equals problem but I've never used Enum as managed property. Try to understand as equals method is working in your case.

Comment: No, exactly the other way around. I *was* using MyEnum[], but the Primefaces filter failed as described above. (and now with List<MyEnum> and the omnifaces converter it works). Using MyEnum[] in a selectMenu works like charm without a converter, when I am using it to asign a value to an entity-object, e.g. - But here it is used just for filtering in the datatable and I do not understand why a converter is neccessary in this case (but not in the other).